# If I execute a task from terminal it works, but within a script it don't...Why?

Tags: bash, grep, cat

Tried every step from terminal, one by one. And they work, but when I execute

```
cat $dj_name | grep -Eo "(https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_%:-]*.mp3*" | sort -u > $dj_name-tracks
```

in a script, the script fails leaving the tracks file empty.
Here's the entire script I'm using.
Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Which DJ set are we downloading from hearthis.at? (Find the name right after https://hearthis.at, like /*dj_name*/ and write is EXACTLY)"
read dj_name
mkdir $dj_name
cd $dj_name
wget https://hearthis.at/$dj_name/podcast/ -O $dj_name
cat $dj_name | grep -Eo "(https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_%:-]*.mp3*" | sort -u > $dj_name-tracks
while read a b; do wget --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'dir="$dir1"=&file="$file1"' --no-check-certificate "$a" "$b"; done > $dj_name-tracks
echo "If no error messages are displayed, you are probably good to go. Enjoy."
exit
```

Comment: Try pasting your code into https://shellcheck.net

Comment: The standard technique for debugging a script is to put `set -x` at the beginning, so it will show a transcript of the commands with all the variables filled in.

Comment: Avoid putting long blocks on a single line, like your `while` loop. Spread it over multiple lines to make it easier to read.

Comment: Enclose the variables in double quotes, otherwise, if they contain spaces, the result is not what you expect. For example, if the value of `$dj_name` is `foo bar` then the command `mkdir $dj_name` becomes `mkdir foo bar` and it creates two directories (`foo` and `bar`) instead of only one. While this does not break your script, the next command becomes `cd foo bar` and this one definitely fails with the error _"too many arguments"_. Similar for the redirection `> $dj_name-track`, `wget`, etc.

Comment: `exit` at the end of the script is superfluous. The script exits anyway after the last command completes.

Comment: A possible cause for the script not running is the line `#!/bin/bash`. This line tells that the script must be executed with `/bin/bash` and it is possible that your shell is a different one. Maybe `zsh` or just a different version of `bash` located somewhere else. Run `echo $SHELL` in the terminal to find out.

Comment: @axiac, running a script with a `/bin/bash` shebang depends only on `/bin/bash` existing and being a suitable interpreter for the script.  It's not a problem for the user's default shell to be something different.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The OP tested each command in their login shell and they worked then, when they put them in a script (executed with `/bin/bash`) they did not work. A different login shell could be the cause for this behaviour.

Comment: Ah, @axiac, I see what you mean now.  But no, that's not a plausible explanation in conjunction with these particular commands.

Comment: The regex in your `grep` command is wonky.  It doesn't mean what you appear to have intended.  That doesn't explain why why you would see different behavior in your script than on the command line, but frankly, I'm inclined to guess that that comes from not, in fact, executing the same commands.

Comment: Where is input for `while read a b` coming from?

Comment: The issue is not actually with the part of extracting the web links using grep, it works flawlessly inside the script but the thing is on the wget loop part. While executing it erases the correctly created links from previous steps using grep, creating an empty link to download. 
Will stick to that and see where it fails. Thanks @MarkSetchell for the script checker, it only points to add an -r to the read command but it's very useful.
Barmar the reason to use a loop is that it requires several downloads sequentially thus it is a condition.
And about the /bin/bash I'm on Debian, so no point

Comment: The checker also suggests enclosing variables in double quotes, e.g.  `mkdir "$dj_name"` and  `cd "$dj_name"` and so on.

Comment: Yes, in general, but in this particular case it's not relevant...

Comment: @shellter from the previously created list. 
'Read reads a whole line from standard input, splits the line into fields and assigns this fields to the given variables. If there are more pieces than variables, the remaining pieces are assigned to the last variable.'

Comment: It seems you are quoting the bash manual page (that is good), but where is the `standard input` being passed in? I wold expect to see `while read a b ; ... ; done < inputFile` or something like  `{echo first second ; echo third forth ; } | while read a b ; .... ; done` or several other, less common patterns .Did you apply fixes recommended by https://shellcheck.net? If so, update your question with that code and update your comments. Good luck

Comment: Now Simplifying it to "wget -i tracks" and trying to add resume incomplete downloads which seems not possible so far...Thank you @everybody.

Comment: RobertoGonzalez has struggled thru and invented a new, possibly better solution to their problem. I'm voting to reopen so they can accept their own answer and gain valuable reputation points. Is there a better way to solicit reopen votes?

Comment: Regarding ["but in this particular case it's not relevant"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376422/if-i-execute-a-task-from-terminal-it-works-but-within-a-script-it-dont-why#comment136415824_77376422) in reference to the missing quotes - quotes aren't something you add when you need to, they're something you remove when you need to. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Working now, using wget -i directly thus removing loop...Thanks for your tips!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Which DJ set are we downloading from hearthis.at? (Find the name right after https://hearthis.at, like /*dj_name*/ and write it EXACTLY)"
read "dj_name"
mkdir "$dj_name"
cd "$dj_name"
wget https://hearthis.at/$dj_name/podcast/ -O "$dj_name"
cat "$dj_name" | grep -Eo "(https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_%:-]*.mp3*" | sort -u > "$dj_name-tracks"
wget --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'dir="$dir1"=&file="$file1"' --no-check-certificate -i "$dj_name-tracks"
echo "If no error messages are displayed, you are probably good to go. Enjoy."
```

Comment: Learn to use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu. Mouse select text you want to format as `code/data/output/exactTxtErrMsgs` then click the `{}` "icon" in the Edit menu above the text entry box to get correct formatting. Glad you solved your probleml Good luck.

Comment: The only issue with this script is related to wget assigning a number to files with the same name. Then it will end in (usually) listen.mp3 / listen.mp3.1 and so on... The workaround was to add a separated mp3 folder and execute the following command:
ls -v | cat -n | while read n f; do mv -n "$f" "$dj_name-$n.mp3"; done

Comment: Well done on continuing to improve your code! but please update your Answer with your fix and I'll upvote it and you can accept your own answer after 48 hrs of posting your original question. (Not sure I can vote on an A after the Q is closed of if you can accept your answer, we might have to get your Q reopened, which often isn't easy). Good luck..